# Save selected item in List

Tags: swiftui

This looks like a very simple thing, but I can't figure out how to do this:

I have a List embedded in a `NavigationView`, containing a `NavigationLink` to view the detail of the item.
I have a save bar button where I would like to save the selected item. But how can I access the selected item?
It isn't visible in the button's action closure.

```
struct ItemList : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var items: ItemsModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(items) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetail(item: item)) {
                    Text(item.name)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Item"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                self.save(/*item: item */) // How can I access item here?
            }, label: {
                Text("Save")
            }))
        }
    }

    func save(item: Item) {
        print("Saving...")
    }
}
```

Comment: I also had a hard time with this - because I come from an OOP background, not a reactive one. You're almost there. What data in `ItemsModel` do you wish to update? Basically, put the *updating* of state in your *model* and then inform `SwiftUI` how to trigger it via your `ItemsModel`. And of course, once the model is updated, any views looking at `items` will reflect that change.

Comment: @dfd How is your comment related to the question? The question is about having access to the _selected_ item of the list (of `items`), not updating the state of the model...

Comment: I focused on the title and the word *"Save" - doesn't that mean updating the model? Trust me, I'm just trying to help, and if I'm not, I'll gladly delete my comment.

Comment: @dfd I think you are right, I should put the selected state in the model. I think I will try to add a selectedItem property to the ItemsModel, which will be nil when no items are selected, and see how that goes

Comment: That's what I needed too. My model was a "recipe" of "steps", and selecting a step from a list was stumping me until I **finally** grokked that I need to completely separate my model from the views - `UIKit` makes it easy to keep them too much together. In my case I think a `step`, no matter how it's defined, is very similar to your `item`. And yes, tracking the current one being edited should be part of the model. Keep your views bound to the data, but keep the actual functions for maintaining state to the model.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation links are not obligatory to accomplish this.
[image: Selected items from a list]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    struct Ocean: Identifiable, Hashable {
        let name: String
        var id: Self { self }
    }
    private var oceans = [
        Ocean(name: "Pacific"),
        Ocean(name: "Atlantic"),
        Ocean(name: "Indian"),
        Ocean(name: "Southern"),
        Ocean(name: "Arctic")
    ]
    
    @State private var selectedOceans = [Ocean]()
    @State private var multiSelection = Set<Ocean.ID>()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Oceans")
            List(oceans, selection: $multiSelection) {
                Text($0.name)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Oceans")
            .environment(\.editMode, .constant(.active))
            .onTapGesture {
                // Walkaround: try how it works without `asyncAfter()`
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.05, execute: {
                    selectedOceans = Array(multiSelection)
                    print(selectedOceans)
                })
            }
            Divider()
            Text("Selected oceans")
            List(selectedOceans, selection: $multiSelection) {
                Text($0.name)
            }
        }
        Text("\(multiSelection.count) selections")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```